# Send Order Email From Admin Panel

Tags: magento2, order-email

How can I send order confirmation emails to the customers, who have completed orders from the front end?
I know by default Magento sends transactional email when any new order is placed, but what I want is to have an option in bulk operation to send order email from sales -> order grid admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/magevision/magento2-mass-email-customers

I know add a 3rd party link on stackoverflow is not good idea but this extension will help you :)

Comment: Thank you I already using looked this extension, but this extension only sends some static general emails, But I want with order details of each particular order.

Comment: you can edit "Controller/Adminhtml/Email/MassSend.php"  Send() function as per your need

Comment: I posted below answer you just need to add code in foreach for send email

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Class\Where\You\Want\Custom\OrderSender;

use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;

class Test {
    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository;
    
    /**
     * @var OrderSender
     */
    private OrderSender $orderSender;

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param OrderSender $orderSender
     */
    public function __construct(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        OrderSender $orderSender
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
    }

    public function someFunction() {
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get(8); // Your logic to get the order
        $this->orderSender->send($order); // Order sender has custom identity that ignores settings
    }
}
```

**or using objectmanager (just for knowledge. Using objectmanager is bad practice)**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);

$emailSender = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender');
$emailSender->send($order);
```